# UK visa Application Status: no updates for 12 days

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, application-status

I applied for a two-year business visa for the UK 12 days ago in VFS Delhi. I also opted for the SMS/Email facility. However, I did not receive any updates from their side. Also, there is no interface where I can follow-up or check my visa status.

Should I be concerned about the status of my application? How can I find out how it is going?

Comment: Isn't there anywhere stated on their website how long it takes, approximately? Or maybe something like "contact us if you haven't heard from us in x days"?

Comment: No. I am afraid.

Comment: If it is urgent, you could maybe call to explain them your situation and ask them for information.

Comment: Well, Go to this link to track your visa application by entering your application reference number and date of birth..  

https://www.vfsglobal.org/ukg-passporttracking/applicanttrackstatus1.aspx?undefined

Answer (score 11):

The [UKVI site](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/new-delhi-india/visits-visas/long-term-visit-more-than-6-months) reports the following...

[image]

So if you have applied for a long-term business visa, the maximum wait is currently 30 days.  Note that this is at odds with the [VFS page](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/India/frequently_asked_questions.html)...

[image]

Which says 90% are processed within 15 days.  In either case since you signed up for SMS alerts, you would have had at least two messages by now: the date your application was entered into [Proviso](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/central_referencing_system_provi) and the date your documents were assembled for the decision-maker.

If you have not heard anything, you should contact your VFS and try to confirm that your application was indeed submitted.  You can also try to [upgrade your application](http://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/India/user_pay_services.html#6) to priority if you qualify.

Finally, *if* you used a go-between travel agent to present your application to the VFS, then you may have to consider contacting the police.