# How long should we wait for a UK Visitor Visa in New Delhi?

Tags: visas, uk

We applied for a visitor visa (less than 6 month)in New Delhi at 10 June but nobody is given answer when we will got visa. Already our passports in embassy from last 40 days

At least they should be return passports when time is go more than 15 days.
I got same visa 3 years ago in 15 days in Istanbul. Some body can help us?
When we will get it?

Comment: see also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48702/uk-visa-application-status-no-updates-for-12-days

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SCREAM.